# Initialization of std::initializer_list<std::string_view>

Tags: c++, constructor, c++17, language-lawyer

The following program

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <string_view>

inline constexpr std::initializer_list<std::string_view> s = { "" };

int main() {}
```

compiles with current Clang (12.0.0) but not with current GCC (11.0.0 20201028). With GCC it produces the error

```
prog.cc:4:67: error: modification of '<temporary>' is not a constant expression
    4 | inline constexpr std::initializer_list<std::string_view> s = { "" };
      |                                                                    ^
```

From [[dcl.init.list/5]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.init.list#5) and the fact that the *string_view(char const*)* constructor is *constexpr*, I assume that Clang's behavior is right here.

Is that correct?

Comment: I haven't read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59539488/weird-behaviour-constexpr-with-stdinitializer-list) post thoroughly, but I think it can give you some ideas on what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. It is a [GCC bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=92181).